# How to change the table content dynamically in html using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/edMGf/) to change the table content dynamically

The script is in `jQuery`

Original `jQuery` code to change the table content dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var data1 = [
        { field1: 'value a1', field2: 'value a2', field3: 'value a3', field4: 'value a4' },
        { field1: 'value b1', field2: 'value b2', field3: 'value b3', field4: 'value b4' },
        { field1: 'value c1', field2: 'value c2', field3: 'value c3', field4: 'value c4' }
        ];

    var data2 = [
        { field1: 'new value a1', field2: 'new value a2', field3: 'new value a3' },
        { field1: 'new value b1', field2: 'new value b2', field3: 'new value b3' },
        { field1: 'new value b1', field2: 'new value b2', field3: 'new value b3' },
        { field1: 'new value c1', field2: 'new value c2', field3: 'new value c3' }
        ];

    function loadTable(tableId, fields, data) {
        //$('#' + tableId).empty(); //not really necessary
        var rows = '';
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var row = '<tr>';
            $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
                row += '<td>' + item[field+''] + '</td>';
            });
            rows += row + '<tr>';
        });
        $('#' + tableId + ' tbody').html(rows);
    }

    loadTable('data-table', ['field2', 'field1', 'field3'], data1);

    $('#btn-update').click(function(e) {
        loadTable('data-table', ['field2', 'field1', 'field3'], data2);
    });

});
```

I have a similar code but data content is

like 
'rollno','name', 'state', 'city','class', 'age'

```
[
 { 'rollno': 'value a1', 'name': 'value a2', 'state': 'value a3', 'city': 'value a4', 'class': 'value a5', 'age': 'value a6' },
 { 'rollno': 'value b1', 'name': 'value b2', 'state': 'value b3', 'city': 'value b4', 'class': 'value b5', 'age': 'value b6' },
 { 'rollno': 'value c1', 'name': 'value c2', 'state': 'value c3', 'city': 'value c4' , 'class': 'value c5', 'age': 'value c6'}
 ];
```

instead of

```
[
 { field1: 'value a1', field2: 'value a2', field3: 'value a3', field4: 'value a4' },
 { field1: 'value b1', field2: 'value b2', field3: 'value b3', field4: 'value b4' },
 { field1: 'value c1', field2: 'value c2', field3: 'value c3', field4: 'value c4' }
 ];
```

My code

```
function get_student_filters() {
    var selected_city = document.getElementById("student_city_selected").value;
    var selected_state = document.getElementById("student_state_selected").value;
    var selected_class = document.getElementById("student_class_selected").value;

    var selected_student_filter_data = {
        s_city:selected_city,
        s_state:selected_state,
        s_class:selected_class
    };
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/filter_student",
          traditional: "true",
          async:false,
          timeout: 40000,
          data: JSON.stringify({selected_student_filter_data}),
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(selected_student){

            var selected_student_data = JSON.stringify(selected_student)

            // Recevied data from the flask of the selected data from the table
            $(document).ready(function(selected_student_data) {

                // Function to fill the table
                    function loadTable(tableId, fields, data) {
                        // $('#' + tableId).empty(); //not really necessary
                        var rows = '';
                        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                            var row = '<tr>';
                            $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
                                row += '<td>' + item[field+''] + '</td>';
                            });
                            rows += row + '<tr>';
                        });
                        $('#' + tableId + ' tbody').html(rows);
            // call function to populate the table
            loadTable('studetnt_table', ['rollno','name', 'state', 'city','class', 'age'], selected_student_data);
                    }
          }
          });
}
```

Nothing gets printed on the table

Two issues

1) Data that i received is not in the same syntax as in the snippet

2) I don't know if `$(document).ready(function(selected_student_data)` `jQuery` will work inside `js` script as i have written above

Could anyone please guide me here

PS
This is not on `button click` but on the option that the user selects for the drop down of the column in `city` ,`class` and `state` [How to make dropdown list filter for a table using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770982/how-to-make-dropdown-list-filter-for-a-table-using-jquery)

Comment: The data looks exactly the same to me: it doesn't matter if there is quotes around your key in your object: they don't make a difference in your case.

Comment: @Terry How do i populate the table, if there is no issue data field? I have updated it now

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.

- Don't do `JSON.stringify({selected_student_filter_data})` unless your
  server expects an object with a `selected_student_filter_data`
  property. That's [ES2015 Object Property Shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).
- Don't put `$(document).ready` inside the AJAX success
  response, have the function `loadTable` outside and call it from
  there and once from `$(document).ready`.
- `selected_student_data = JSON.stringify(selected_student)` will put a string value for 
  `selected_student_data`. You don't wanna do that. You need
  `JSON.parse` but jQuery will do that for you if you set the response
  header `Content-type: application/json`.

I suggest you first wipe out everything inside `success` function and just check and understand if you get correct data and in what form. Then create the function `loadTable` that will populate the data to the table.

```
...
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data); // Open console and check the data you get
}
...
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` doesn't work, `JSON.stringify` gives the data in the above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind different implementation, Check the following solution.

Dynamically renders the table content.

```js
function addTable(data, headers) {

  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myTable");
  myTableDiv.innerHTML = "";

  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border = '1';

  var tableHeader = document.createElement('THEAD');
  table.appendChild(tableHeader);

  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var n = data.length;
  var m = headers.length;
  var thKeys;
  if (n > 0) {
    thKeys = Object.keys(data[0]);
  }

  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '75';
    td.innerText = thKeys[j];
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      td.width = '75';
      td.innerText = data[i][thKeys[j].toLowerCase()];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }

  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);

}

var data = [
  {
    "title": "021",
    "score": 86,
    "ref": "desc 021",
    "id": "ABC021"
  },
  {
    "title": "022",
    "score": 72,
    "ref": "desc 022",
    "id": "ABC022"
  }
];

addTable(data, ['Title', 'Score']);

function updateTable() {
  addTable(data, ['Title', 'Score', 'Ref', 'Id']);
}

function reset() {
  addTable(data, ['Title', 'Score']);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTable"></div>

<button onclick="updateTable()">update table</button>

<button onclick="reset()">reset table</button>
```