# How to apply drop-down filter on generated table using PHP, JSON or AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a project in which there is a main lead table with rows and column values as in MYSQL table. I want to add some value based filter using drop-down to applied over the table so that view of large number of rows in table can be minimized.

But i am confused to how to generate the table each time when i apply filter.

Please guide me and comment if any code part is needed. Its screenshot is attached.

[image: See Project]

[image: File Structure]

Below is a part of my code as screenshot attached above and is inside HTML body.

`Dashboard.html`

```
 <!-- View Main Lead Table with Filters  -->
            <section class="operation" id="view_lead_info" style="display: none;">

                <!-- Filters -->

                <div class="row">                

                            <div class="col">
                                <label><p><b>Select Filter</b></p></label>                    
                            </div>          

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                Lead Status:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                                <select><option>Select</option>
                                    <?php                                                
                                        echo "<option value='Active'>Active Leads</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='Paused'>Paused Leads</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='Expired'>Expired Leads</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='Unsubscribed'>Unsubscribed</option>";
                                    ?>                            
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>                         
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                Campaign Status:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                                <select><option>Select</option>
                                    <?php                                                
                                        echo "<option value='Active'>Active</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='Paused'>Paused</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='Expired'>Expired</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='Unsubscribed'>Unsubscribed</option>";
                                    ?>                            
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                Company Name:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-3">                                       

                                    <?php                                            

                                        include('./server/connection.php');

                                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info ORDER By Company ASC";
                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                                                                                                                  
                                        echo "<select>";
                                        echo "<option>select</option>";                                            
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='$row[Company]'> $row[Company] </option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";

                                    ?>                          

                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                State:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-4">                                       

                                    <?php                                            

                                        include('./server/connection.php');

                                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_state_info ORDER By StateName ASC";
                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                           

                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                                        echo "<select name='StateName'>";
                                        echo "<option>select</option>";                                            
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='$row[StateName]'> $row[StateName] </option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";

                                    ?>                          

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                Country:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                                <?php 

                                    include('./server/connection.php');

                                    $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_country_info ORDER By CountryName ASC";
                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                                    echo "<select name='CountryName'>";
                                    echo "<option>select</option>";
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo "<option value='$row[CountryName]'> $row[CountryName] </option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";

                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                Firm Type:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                                <?php 

                                    include('./server/connection.php');

                                    $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_firm_type_info ORDER By FirmType_Value ASC";
                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                                    echo "<select name='FirmType'>";
                                    echo "<option>select</option>";
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo "<option value='$row[FirmType_Value]'> $row[FirmType_Value] </option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";

                                ?>       
                            </div>
                        </div>                         
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                Firm Size:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-4">

                                <?php 

                                    include('./server/connection.php');

                                    $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_firm_size_info ORDER By FirmSize_Id ASC";
                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                                    echo "<select name='FirmSize'>";
                                    echo "<option>select</option>";
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo "<option value='$row[FirmSize_Value]'> $row[FirmSize_Value] </option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";

                                ?>

                            </div>
                        </div> 

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                Tech Area:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                                <?php 

                                    include('./server/connection.php');

                                    $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_tech_area_info ORDER By TechAreaName ASC";
                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                                    $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                                    echo "<select name='TechAreaName'>";
                                    echo "<option>select</option>";
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo "<option value='$row[TechAreaName]'> $row[TechAreaName] </option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";

                                ?> 
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>                

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                Start Date:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-3-of-4">                          
                                    <?php 

                                    echo "<input type='date' name='startdate'>";

                                    ?>                                    
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                End Date:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col span-3-of-4">                            
                                    <?php 

                                    echo "<input type='date' name='enddate'>";

                                    ?>                                     
                            </div>
                        </div>                         
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">               

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-3-of-4">

                            </div>               
                        </div> 
                    </div>    
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-3-of-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                        <label></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Search">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <!-- Main Tables Campaign and Lead Table                        -->

                <div class="row">

                    <!-- MAIN TABLE-->

                    <div class="col" >



                        <button class="viewMainTable" onclick="viewMainTable();" name="viewMainTable">Lead Table</button>
                        <button class="viewCampaignTable" onclick="viewCampaignTable();" name="viewCampaignTable">Campaign Table</button>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col span-4-of-4">

                                <table class="display_table" id='main_lead_table' style="display: none;">                                    

                                    <th>Sr.No.</th>
                                    <th>LeadID - Name</th>
                                    <th>Company</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                    <th>Communication</th>                                                         
                                    <th>Last Contact Date</th>
                                    <th>Next Contact Date</th>
                                    <th>Lead Status</th> 
                                    <th>Details</th>                            

                                    <?php

                                    include('./server/connection.php');                                    

                                    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_main_lead_info`";

                                    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

                                    $i = 1;

                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                                   


                                                  printf( "<tr>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>                                                                
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>   
                                                            </tr>",

                                                            $i,
                                                            $row['Lead_Id']." - ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'],
                                                            $row['Company'],
                                                            $row['State']."<br>".$row['Country'],
                                                            $row['Phone']."<br>".$row['Email'],
                                                            date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['LastContactDate'])),
                                                            date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['NextContactDate'])),                                                          
                                                            $row['LeadStatus'],
                                                            "Click Here"

                                                            );

                                                    $i = $i+1;

                                                }

                                    ?>


                                </table> 

                                <table class = "display_table" id = 'campaign_table' style = "display: none; ">                                    

                                    <th>Sr.No.</th>
                                    <th>Lead Id</th>
                                    <th>Campaign Name</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Start Date</th>
                                    <th>End Date</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Details</th>

                                    <?php

                                    function getleadname($leadid){

                                        include('./server/connection.php'); 

                                        $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_main_lead_info` WHERE Lead_Id = $leadid";

                                        $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

                                        $i = 1;

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                            $leadidandname = $row['Lead_Id']." - ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'];

                                        } 

                                        return $leadidandname;

                                    }

                                    include('./server/connection.php');                                    

                                    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_campaign_info`";

                                    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

                                    $i = 1;

                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                                   


                                                  printf( "<tr>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>                                                                
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>
                                                                <td>%s</td>

                                                            </tr>",

                                                            $i,
                                                            getleadname($row['CampaignLead_Id']),
                                                            $row['CampaignName'],
                                                            $row['CampaignDescription'],
                                                            date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['CampaignStartDate'])),
                                                        date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['CampaignEndDate'])),                              
                                                            $row['CampaignStatus'],                                                        
                                                            "Click Here"

                                                            );

                                                    $i = $i+1;



                                                }

                                    ?>
                                </table>                                                             

                            </div>                       
                        </div> 

                    </div>                              

                </div>  

            </section>
```

Script is used to change table display style and is inside `dashboard.html`.

```
<script>
                 function viewMainTable(){

                        var x = document.getElementById('main_lead_table');

                        var y = document.getElementById('campaign_table');

                        if (!x.style.display || x.style.display === "none")
                        {
                            x.style.display = "block";
                            y.style.display = "none";      

                        }
                        else{
                            x.style.display = "none";
                        }     


                    }


                    function viewCampaignTable(){

                        var x = document.getElementById('campaign_table');

                        var y = document.getElementById('main_lead_table');

                        if (!x.style.display || x.style.display === "none")
                        {
                            x.style.display = "block";
                            y.style.display = "none";      

                        }
                        else{
                            x.style.display = "none";
                        }       

                    }

             </script>
```

Comment: Hello, you need to add a function javascript to get changes on the select. In the function, you need to get the value that was selected and generate an AJAX to the backend with this value and there, execute queries to DB.
After that, get new values and return to frontend in format json (for example) and generate again the select.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22991256/2209876

Comment: i need some good example to how to get the mysql data from JSON and update the display table dynamically.

Comment: @MaximilianoSchvindt would it be possible to change the way of executing MySQL Queries using PHP, by executing with AJAX and update table rows based on filter section?

Comment: Another advice, change html to php in the dashboard file because you have php in the file. PHP is executed on the server-side, so, when you return the page to frontend you don't have php anymore. If you need some information from db you need to implement endpoints to connect frontend with backend.

Comment: also what about filters, how can i apply the filter to generated table. is i need to run again MySQL query.

Comment: I think this is what i needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770982/how-to-make-dropdown-list-filter-for-a-table-using-jquery